# Is there any difference between Underscore _.map and the JS built-in function?

Tags: javascript, lodash, underscore.js

Looked around but couldn't find this question. Is there any practical difference between Underscore (or Lodash) `_.map` and the `map` function that's built into JavaScript? Can I use them interchangeably?

ie: is

```
_.map(myArr, a => {
  // do stuff...
})
```

equal to

```
myArr.map(a => {
  // do stuff...
}
```

Comment: They are not interchangable.  Lodash's version takes different kinds of parameters. 
 Check the documentation on each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two major differences between `Array.prototype.map` and Underscore's (or Lodash's) free-standing `map` function.

Firstly, `map` works on objects without a `length` property while `Array.prototype.map` does not:

```
import { map } from 'underscore';

const square = x => x * x;
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

map(obj, square); // fine, [1, 4, 9]
[].map.call(obj, square); // error
```

Secondly, like all Underscore collection functions, `map` supports convenient iteratee shorthands that `Array.prototype.map` does not:

```
map([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]], 'length'); // [3, 2, 1]

const people = [
    {name: 'Joe', occupation: 'news presenter'},
    {name: 'Jane', occupation: 'firefighter'},
];

map(people, 'occupation');
// ['news presenter', 'firefighter']

map(people, ['occupation', 2]);
// ['w', 'r'] (third character of occupation)

map(people, {name: Jane}); // [false, true]
```

A more minor difference, which only applies to Underscore, is that `map` supports an optional third argument that lets you bind the callback to this argument:

```
const sourceObject = {
    greet(name) {
        return this.greeting + name;
    },
    greeting: 'Hello ',
};

const bindObject = {
    greeting: 'Goodbye ',
};

const names = map(people, 'name');

map(names, sourceObject.greet, sourceObject);
// [ 'Hello Joe', 'Hello Jane' ]

map(names, sourceObject.greet, bindObject);
// [ 'Goodbye Joe', 'Goodbye Jane' ]
```

You can generally safely replace `Array.prototype.map` by Underscore's `map`, but not the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

They are different functions; if you were to look at [Lodash's source code for `map`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/map.js) you would see that it does *not* use `Array.prototype.map` "under the hood".

The primary difference is that Lodash "guards" a bunch of its functions for use inside its `map` (and similar iteration functions).  From the Lodash documentation (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map):

> The guarded methods are: ary, chunk, curry, curryRight, drop,
> dropRight, every, fill, invert, parseInt, random, range, rangeRight,
> repeat, sampleSize, slice, some, sortBy, split, take, takeRight,
> template, trim, trimEnd, trimStart, and words

Comment: What does "guard" mean here? And where are these methods listed in the source you linked?

Comment: "Guarded" means they they can be safely used as iteratees for functions like `_.map`.  A good example of a guarded method is `_.parseInt`.  If you use it as the iteratee, its second parameter, the radix, doesn't get used, even though `_.map` passes three parameters.  If you use `parseInt`, you can get unexpected behavior.

Comment: A basic demo I set up to show this off:  https://jsfiddle.net/nb0vte4y/

Comment: The guarding is arguably a property of the guarded functions in question, not a difference between `_.map` and `Array.prototype.map`. I certainly wouldn't call it the primary difference, since there is a lot of functionality in Underscore and Lodash that you just don't get from the standard.